# Trouble with sparse matrices in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, sparse-matrix

The following code gives me the first k eigenvalues of a certain big matrix. Because of the symmetries of the matrix, the eigenvalues are in pairs, one positive and the other negative, with the same absolute value. This is indeed the case if I run the code with the exact matrices, without using the sparse version. However when I make them sparse, the resulting eigenvalues appear to lose the sign information, as now the pairs can be both negative, or both positive, depending on the number I put on "nspins" (which controls the size of the matrix). The variable "sparse" controls whether I use sparse matrices or not.

This issue gives me considerable trouble. Can anybody tell me why the sparse version of the computation gives wrong signs, and how to fix it?

```
sparse = 1; (*Parameter that controls whether I will use sparse \
matrices, 0 means not sparse, 1 means sparse*)

(*Base matrices of my big matrix*)
ox = N[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
oz = N[{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}];
id = N[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];

(*Transformation into sparse whether desired*)
If[sparse == 1,
 ox = SparseArray[ox];
 oz = SparseArray[oz];
 id = SparseArray[id];
 ]

(*Dimension of the big matrix, must be even*)
nspins = 8;

(*Number of eigenvalues computed*)
neigenv = 4;

(*Algorithm to create big matrices*)
Do[
  Do[
    If[j == i, mata = ox; matc = oz;, mata = id; matc = id;];
    If[j == 1,
     o[1, i] = mata;
     o[3, i] = matc;
     ,
     o[1, i] = KroneckerProduct[o[1, i], mata];
     o[3, i] = KroneckerProduct[o[3, i], matc];
     ];
    , {j, 1, nspins}];
  , {i, 1, nspins}];

(*Sum of big matrices*)
ham = Sum[o[1, i].o[1, i + 1], {i, 1, nspins - 1}] + 
   o[1, nspins].o[1, 1] + 0.5*Sum[o[3, i], {i, 1, nspins}];

(*Print the desired eigenvalues*)
Do[Print [Eigenvalues[ham, k][[k]]], {k, 1, neigenv}];
```

Comment: I obtain the same results independent of the value of `sparse`, namely, eigenvalues in pairs, one positive and the other negative.  By the way, you will receive far more attention for your questions in the Mathematica community.